# I am trying to query historical blocks for specific events from my contract. Is a full node required for this? Or is a light node or fast node fine?

Tags: events, web3.py

I am having difficulty seeing any events for my contract. They show up in etherscan but not when trying to view them using web3. I am running a light node. Do I need a full or fast node to have access to these events?

I am also using the python implementation of web3: https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py

Using the following code. I can confirm my transaction is in-between the block limits provided to the filter.

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider, IPCProvider
import json
ROPSTEN_RPC = 'http://localhost:8546'
ContractWithEvents = '0x...'
ABI = json.loads("""[{...}]""")
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(ROPSTEN_RPC))
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=ContractWithEvents, abi=ABI)
contract.pastEvents('newUpload', filter_params={'fromBlock':1564421, 'toBlock':1564441}).get()
```

This returns an empty list. When there is at least 1 event fired according to etherscan.

Comment: From my experience a light node was not enough, but a fast node worked to query events.

Comment: v cool, thanks. was suspecting (dreading) that answer